# Flipping bits in a image bytes without decompressing the image

Tags: image-processing, steganography, image-formats

I am interested in flipping few bits in image section of popular image formats such jpg, tiff, png, heic. Let's consider a example.

- Given a image as byte array, few bytes represent the header section say from [0 to N]
- Then few more bytes contain metadata such as exif etc from [N+1 to M]
- Then a lot more bytes contain the image pixels in a compressed format according to some compression algorithm, say [M+1 to X]
- Lastly there is tail section from [X+1 to Z] where Z is length of given byte array.

I am interested in flipping few bits in bytes from [M+1 to X]. I am assuming that these bytes do not contain anything else except compressed bits of the image so when bits are flipped, any image viewer will still work without any loss of image quality.

I need recommendation for java or python libs that can parse the image and give me indices for M+1 and X.

Thanks for reading and helping out in advance.

Best

Comment: Asking recommendations for libraries of external tools is considered of topic. But I'll give you an example of what you want to do. For JPEG after the header, you will the compressed DCT coefficients, you decompress them, modify them and then compress and write them to file again. That's it. That's *all* you have to do but no less.

Comment: “... so when bits are flipped, any image viewer will still work without any loss of image quality.” This is a misunderstanding. If you flip bits you corrupt the compressed stream, and decompressors will no longer be able to decompress the stream. If you want to modify the data, you need to decompress it, change it, then recompress.